# In how many ways can I use 4 colors in a square

Tags: math

I'm doing a program in C but I got stuck in math :D

- > I have a square divided by quadrants. 4 squares inside a square
- > For each quadrant I can have a color. Red,Blue,Green and Yellow.

**In how many ways I can combine this?**

I thought it was `4*4*4*4` but I need to subtract some possibilities( for example: green,green,blue,blue is the same when I trade blue for blue or green for green. It's the same combination.

Comment: What do you mean by "trade blue for blue"?  Either a quadrant is blue or it isn't; there aren't different blues.

Comment: So there's 256 possibilities? I dont need to substract anything?

Comment: I mean imagine this combination: yellow,red,red,blue the reds are in the diagonal. If i make another combination where it's yellow,red,red,blue it's the same.

Comment: I'm not realy strong in maths. It's about Combinatorics math, you can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics

Comment: I advise you to read your last comment carefully. Do you mean that two patterns are the same if one can be *rotated* to get the other?

Comment: How would you make "yellow, red, red, blue" twice?

Comment: Suppose you only had 2 colors (white,black) and the square was cut in half.  What would the list of combinations, as you understand them, of assigning colors to halves be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for a permutation without repetition, which in your case would be 4! = 24.

Comment: In what way can "green, green, blue, blue" be considered to have no repetition?

Comment: Agreed, it needs more work.  Any ideas? The 4*4*4*4 from OP would account for an empty set combination...